# Looping through Model Collection and filter a query in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, linq, list

I Have a model in my Web-Application like this:

```
class MyClass 
{
    int ID;
    List<AnotherClass> foo {get; set;}
}

class AnotherClass 
{
    int ID;
    string bar;
}
```

I also have a list of filter-strings given by the user.

```
List<string> filter = new List<string> { "foo", "bar" } //as example
```

What I want is to filter `MyClass` by the given strings like this:

```
var result = context.MyClass.Include(mc => mc.foo);
result = result.Where(x => filter.Any(f => f == x.foo.Select(d => d.bar)));
```

The Problem is: `Select()` returns a List of strings and I can't compare a string with a list of strings.

Anyone an idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault or SingleORDefault it will you only one result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If putting into words what you want is: *Find whichever item in result, if any of its inner class items is present in the filter list*

Try:

```
result.Where(item => item.Any(innerItem => filter.Contains(innerItem.bar)))
```

Or in the other syntax:

```
var output = (from item in result
              from innerItem in item.foo
              where filter.Contains(innerItem.bar)
              select item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Contains`

```
result = result.Where(x => x.foo.Any(i => filter.Contains(i.bar)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need simple `Any` and `Contains` methods, and you could do this.

```
result.Where(x => x.foo.Any(f=> filter.Contains(f.bar));
```